# How to navigate back to previous tab when back button clicked without changing url

Tags: angularjs, tabs, back-button

I am working on an angular application.i navigate to a View where i have a 3 tabs by default 'tab1' is selected,when i click on 'tab2' it get selected .i want to navigate back to 'tab1' when browser back button is clicked.This View has one controller bind to it.i want to navigate to previous tab without loading entire View

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to navigation event and state.direction.

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // do something
  }
  if (direction == 'forward') {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: should i use this code while navigating to next tab?

Comment: this code is listening if the button back or forward is pressed. So use this code in tab2 and redirect to tab1. You need to remember where is back if you have more Views.